# How to sort Array of object list In java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

How to sort Array Of DashboardObjectAIR object If suppose any array object in contains in arrray 0 or 1 location "UnOk" then it should show top.

For below `tempObj` List  the `airObj` should in location 0 in list because it contains "UnOk".

```
DashboardObjectAIR[] airObj = new DashboardObjectAIR[2];

airObj[0] = new DashboardObjectAIR("UnOk");

airObj[1] = new DashboardObjectAIR("Ok");

airObj1[0] = new DashboardObjectAIR( "Ok");

airObj1[1] = new DashboardObjectAIR("Ok");

List<DashboardObjectAIR[]> tempObj = new ArrayList<DashboardObjectAIR[]>();

tempObj.add(airObj);
tempObj.add(airObj1);
```

How can i sort this scnarion:

Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: Can we have the implementation of DashboardObjectAIR..Basically DashboardObjectAIR should be implementing a comparable or you can add a Comparator to compare the DashboardObjectAIR classes in the current class

Comment: Well, you already picked the **keyword** you need to know about: *comparator*. So - you already know which topic to research. Do you really need us to do that for you?

Comment: @GhostCat Can you please explain How to implement this ?

Comment: Thats easy. You turn to Google, there is a box in the middle of the window. You enter the words: "java sorting comparator example". Tada. Magic.

Comment: @GhostCat but here Array of object that the main issue  ?

Comment: Fayaz already told you the point: you want to sort Objects of class DashboardObjectAIR. So, you need a comparator that knows how to compare objects of that class. Thats all there is to know about this!

Comment: @GhostCat Actually, OP doesn't want to sort objects of type `DashboardObjectAIR`. OP wants to sort objects of type `DashboardObjectAIR[]`. If the array contains at least one "UnOk" object, the *array* must be sorted first in the `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

assuming the array will have minimum 2 elements, if not have to add boundary checks

```
    DashboardObjectAIR[] airObj = new DashboardObjectAIR[2];
    airObj[0] = new DashboardObjectAIR("UnOk");
    airObj[1] = new DashboardObjectAIR("Ok");
    DashboardObjectAIR[] airObj1 = new DashboardObjectAIR[2];
    airObj1[0] = new DashboardObjectAIR("Ok");
    airObj1[1] = new DashboardObjectAIR("Ok");
    DashboardObjectAIR[] airObj3 = new DashboardObjectAIR[2];
    airObj3[0] = new DashboardObjectAIR("Ok");
    airObj3[1] = new DashboardObjectAIR("Ok");
    DashboardObjectAIR[] airObj4 = new DashboardObjectAIR[2];
    airObj4[0] = new DashboardObjectAIR("Ok");
    airObj4[1] = new DashboardObjectAIR("UnOk");

    List<DashboardObjectAIR[]> listOfArray = new ArrayList<DashboardObjectAIR[]>();
    listOfArray.add(airObj);
    listOfArray.add(airObj1);
    listOfArray.add(airObj3);
    listOfArray.add(airObj4);

    Comparator<DashboardObjectAIR[]> c = (a1, a2) -> {
        int comp = a2[0].getOk().compareTo(a1[0].getOk()); // note a2 - a1 to have Unok before Ok
        if (comp == 0)
            return a2[1].getOk().compareTo(a1[1].getOk());
        else
            return comp;
    };
    List<DashboardObjectAIR[]> sorted = listOfArray.stream().sorted(c).collect(Collectors.toList());
    sorted.forEach(arr -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)));
```

output

```
[DashboardObjectAIR [ok=UnOk], DashboardObjectAIR [ok=Ok]]
[DashboardObjectAIR [ok=Ok], DashboardObjectAIR [ok=UnOk]]
[DashboardObjectAIR [ok=Ok], DashboardObjectAIR [ok=Ok]]
[DashboardObjectAIR [ok=Ok], DashboardObjectAIR [ok=Ok]]
```

**Edit-1**

Array of unknown size [Thanks @Andreas]

```
    Comparator<DashboardObjectAIR[]> c1 = (a1, a2) -> {
        return Arrays.stream(a2).map(DashboardObjectAIR::getOk).sorted().collect(Collectors.joining())
                .compareTo(Arrays.stream(a1).map(DashboardObjectAIR::getOk).sorted().collect(Collectors.joining()));

    };
```

Comment: You're silently using the trick of sorting by String *descending*, by inverting the use of `a2` and `a1` in the `Comparator`. It's such an easy thing to overlook, and could be a mistake, that you should always document (comment) when applying tricks like that. At the very least, you should have explained in the answer.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you, will add comments

Comment: Also beware that task was to sort arrays that contains "UnOk" first. This code will sort `[UnOk,Ok]` before `[Ok,UnOk]`, which may not be desirable if original order should otherwise remain intact.

Comment: @Andreas in the Q its mentioned like element 0 or 1 to contain 'Unok' , that's why

Comment: Question text just says that array should show top if *either* index position is `"UnOk"`. It doesn't say what to do if more than one array fits the criteria. It doesn't say how `[UnOk,Ok]` and `[Ok,UnOk]` should sort relative to each other. I was simply pointing out that your `Comparator` implementation will always sort `[UnOk,Ok]` before `[Ok,UnOk]`, rather than retain the order they were originally in. Whether that is desirable is entirely up to OP, I just wanted OP to be aware of it.

Comment: @Andreas Got it, modified the `Comparator`

Comment: @Andreas Thank you, I added another `Comparator`, I'd have taken isOk as `boolean` instead of `String`

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity, I will assume that `DashboardObjectAIR` has a `boolean isOk()` method, for testing whether the object is "UnOk" or "Ok".

The goal is to sort a `List<DashboardObjectAIR[]>` such that arrays that contain an "UnOk" `DashboardObjectAIR` object will sort first.

We can use the fact that [`Boolean.compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#compareTo-java.lang.Boolean-) sorts `false` before `true`, so if we can get a `false` value for a `DashboardObjectAIR[]` that has an "UnOk" object, then it'll be easy.

Using Java 8 Streams, we can easily do that this way:

```
tempObj.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> Arrays.stream(a).allMatch(DashboardObjectAIR::isOk)));
```

Here, we sort the list by examining each element of the list. The element is assigned to `a` of type `DashboardObjectAIR[]` and we then check if all objects of the array are "Ok". If so, we return `true` (sort last), otherwise we return `false` (sort first).

This will work for lists and arrays of any size.

Comment: I think we'd check `anyMatch` because even if one element in array contains `UnOk` it should come first

Comment: @Saravana Which is why `allMatch()` is used, because it will return `false` (sort first) if *any* `isOk` call returns false. Only when *all* elements of the array `isOk`, will it return true and sort last.

Comment: yeah, got it, implementation will be same, flipping the return value, right?

Comment: @Saravana Depends on which return value you're referring to. `allMatch(isOk)` is same as `noneMatch(isUnOk)` and same as `! anyMatch(isUnOk)`. So yeah, you can use `anyMatch()` if you flip *both* return values. *(Preceding assumes at least one element in array)*.